# Link using z-index can't be clicked even though it's on top, in both Firefox & IE

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm trying to get a text link to appear on top of a partly-transparent image, which in turn is on top of a plain coloured background. I want the link-text and image to print when the page is printed, but not the coloured background. (Which is why I'm not using the *background-image* property)

The problem is that although the link appears on top of the image, and the image appears on top of the background as desired, the link cannot be clicked.
It seems to me that if the link appears on top then it should be susceptible to mouse events...

This happens in at least the following browsers: Firefox 6.0 (Windows + Linux), Firefox 3.6 (Windows) and Internet Explorer 7.

Please would somebody tell me if this is a problem with my HTML/CSS, or with the browsers?

Here is some HTML to demonstrate the problem:

```
<html>

  <head>         

    <title>Test</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  </head>

  <body>                               

    <div style="position: relative;z-index: -2; background-color:#333; height:200px;">

      <img style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: -1;" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/280px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" alt="Dice" />  

      <a style="padding:50px; color:#fff;z-index:0;" href="#">Can you click me?</a>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Cheers!

Alex

Comment: Just in case, note you can use a different CSS for each media (printer, screen), so you could just use a different the image instead of relying on the browser removing the plain background?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Not sure I understand. Without using background-image (which won't print), I don't think it's possible to specify a different 'src' attribute for the <img> just by specifying a different CSS stylesheet? Also, the image needs to be specified in the HTML because it will be added by a WYSIWYG editor by non-technical staff.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The issue is mainly caused using negative z-index values, which seems to be making the parent div capture the mouse events.  Use positive indexes, and assign `position:relative` to the link to get the expected behaviour, because without explicit positioning z-index will not do anything.

Comment: Just changing z-index values to positive ones doesn't fix the issue. The position:relative is mandatory, though.

Comment: Also, negative numbers are explicitly allowed (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! I had already tried positive z-index values, but it was the position:relative on the link that makes all the difference. (Otherwise the link appears behind the image.)

Comment: Yeah, as @jjmontes said below, you must explicitly set positioning to absolute, relative or fixed in order to use z-index. A point I rather failed to mention.

Comment: To anyone reading this not sure that this is the answer you are looking for, it is! You don't need to declare a top/left position for your <a> link, just make it "position:relative;" and it will work. I read this answer, dismissed it, worked for almost another hour on it, eventually tried this and it worked!

Comment: Critical point is the **parent** div captures the mouse events. Don't get caught trying to apply z-index to the child element.

Comment: Adding position: relative helped me out.

Comment: i'm using an image tag inside a Carousel, and I'm facing the same issue, I want an onClick on click of the image tag:
<div onClick={()=>{history.push('/')}} style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}><img style={{position: "relative", top: "35px", left: "11px",  zIndex: "10"}} src={backArrowIcon} /></div>

Comment: I have positive zIndex and position: relative. but still have the issue. Coulld the <Carousel> in parent level be causing this issue?

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was dealing with some unexplained [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) in CSS (specifically the value `all`), which caused some elements to catch events apparently triggered from a different (non-ancestor!) part of the DOM.

I removed all `pointer-events` from the CSS.

I know this question already has an accepted answer, but my symptoms match the OP, so maybe my tip might help a future struggler like me.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above solution worked for my specific problem. I would recommend using above solutions first and if that does not work set pointer events to none (does not work for IE<=10).

```
.some-horizontal-container {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

You can also use `visibility: hidden` for the div that overlays the clickable element under it.

Please check out this article for more details:https://blog.lysender.com/2014/09/css-elements-covered-by-a-container-div-not-clickable/

Answer (score 4):

Two notes:

1) The z-index attribute can only be used on positioned elements (absolute, relative or fixed). Your  element is not.

2) *[Edited: Not related]* Your top element (the  with z-index: 0) is located inside your background element (the  with z-index: -2).

The following works, you can play with it at: http://jsfiddle.net/5MpFn/

```
<html>

  <head>         

    <title>Test</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  </head>

  <body>                               

    <div style="position: relative;z-index: -2; background-color:#333; height:200px;">

      <img style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: -1;" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/280px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" alt="Dice" />  



    </div>

      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0;left: 0; padding:50px; z-index:0;" >
      <a href="#" style="color:#fff;">Can you click me?</a>      
      </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks for looking at this! It is much appreciated· I'm curious to know what's wrong with having a child element with a different z-index to its parent? I.e. why you have taken the <a> out of the  <div background-color #333>.

Comment: Sorry, that was not related to your issue. The only reason I'd advise not to do it is because that model will make events on the <a> element bubble up in an "unnatural" order (an order different to what is shown on the screen).